# Disocrd.js how i sent message to all members all server client.on('ready')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How i sent message all members all server with client.on('ready') ??

Discord.js Version 11.4.2

```js
client.on('ready', message  => {
  client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.size} servers have members ${client.users.size}`+` | !help `, { type: 'WATCHING' })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
   client.channels.forEach((channel) => {
      guild.channel.send('Whatever you want to send')
   })
})
```

For every channel of every guild it says 'Whatever you want'

Comment: I'm discord.js version 11.4.2 can you help me ? 
this command can't use in this version is it say 
" TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined "

Comment: You should use version v12, it's better and has more features and is easier to use. Also you didn't specify the version in your question yesterday

Comment: version 12 how i sent message all members in server?